# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-2010

App is running in Visual Studio (am using flutter codebase) but not running app in XCode.

Am getting error like this :

> export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=11E801a
> export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=1170
> export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=1100
> export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=1170
> export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH=Evoke.app/XPCServices
> export YACC=yacc
> export arch=undefined_arch
> export variant=normal
> **/bin/sh -c /Users/narendrabiswa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-havrwbirkfzqryfrjadmbfcxsajm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh**
>
> **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

Answer (score 1):

I Got the Solution...

Changed -> Release mode to Debug mode

Project Targets - > EditScheme -> Run -> Info -> Build configuration -> Debug